# How can I improve this amateur shot of sunrise?

Tags: learning, amateur, sunrise

I've recently started taking photographs of things I find beautiful on my phone camera. I'd like to get experts opinion on how I can improve.[image: pic of today's sunrise I shot]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you'd like to improve, or what you're going for?

Answer (score 5):

In low light on a phone camera with little in the way of user-adjustment, your primary objective is to keep the camera still.

Find a wall you can rest it on, & if possible use a delay timer, so you're not actually holding the phone as the picture is taken.

If there is nothing suitable to rest the phone on find a wall/fence/tree to lean against.
Keep your arms tight to your body & the phone tight to your face.
Hold your breath as you take the picture.

Comment: Thanks! Is the low light general advice for sunrise shots or should I have taken this picture in low light? Also does this shot look shaky?

Comment: Advice for any low light shot, which includes sunrise/set. Your eyes see a lot better than a camera does in that kind of light. & yes, you can see movement in the shot, look at the smaller points of light for a clear indication.